# Why, when calling a function with self on the parent class, the child class is actually run in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I have two abstract classes with the following definition:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):

    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.List = lst

    @abstractmethod
    def __enter__(self) -> 'Component':
        return self

    @abstractmethod
    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        pass

class B(ABC):

    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.List = lst

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        pass
```

Now, I have a class that inherits from these:

```
class C(A, B):

    def __init__(self, lst):
        A.__init__(self, lst)
        B.__init__(self, lst)

    def __enter__(self) -> 'C':
        self.List.append('C.__enter__')
        self.run()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        self.List.append('C.__exit__')

    def run(self):
        self.List.append('C.run')
```

Finally, I have a class that inherits from `C`:

```
class D(C):

    def __init__(self, lst):
        super().__init__(lst)

   def __enter__(self) -> 'D':
       self.List.append('D.__enter__')
       super().__enter__()
       return self

   def __exit__(self, *exc):
       super().__exit__()
       self.List.append('D.__exit__')

   def run(self):
       self.List.append('D.run')
       super().run()
```

Now, my code looks like this:

```
my_d = D( ['start'] )
with my_d:
    pass
print(my_d)
```

From my understanding of how `super()` works this should produce the following:

```
[ start,
  D.__enter__,
  C.__enter__,
  C.run,
  C.__exit__,
  D.__exit__ ]
```

but what actually happens is:

```
[ start,
  D.__enter__,
  C.__enter__,
  D.run,
  C.run,
  C.__exit__,
  D.__exit__ ]
```

Nowhere do I explicitly call `D.run` and yet `D.run` is called.

This doesn't really make sense to me unless, when I call `super().__enter__` in D, `self` somehow thinks it's still inside `D` when it's actually in `C`. Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Comment: `self` doesn't "think it's inside" anything. `self` is just a variable. It holds a reference to an object. That object's type doesn't change just because you're executing a `C` method.

Comment: The `self` object, when inside the class `C` is still a reference the object of class `D`. So the executed function is the `D.run` not `C.run`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you call `C.run` when you invoke `D.run`:

```
class  D(C):


def run(self):
    self.List.append('D.run')
    super().run()  # this will add 'C.run' to self.List
```

just the same as with `__exit__` and `__enter__`.

`D.run` is called from the chain `D.__enter__` -> `C.__enter__` which now calls `self.run()` (and as `self` has `type` `D` this will call `D.run` -> `C.run`).

`self` does not think it is 'inside `D`'; `self` *is* of the type `D`.

---

if you want to have your desired output you could just not override `run` in `D`; that way only `C.run` would be called.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. As you can see from the code I submitted, I do not _explicitly_ call `D.run`. I call `D.__enter__` which calls `C.__enter__`. Then `C.__enter__` calls `self.run`. Are you saying that the call to `self.run` is calling `D.run`?

Comment: @Woody1193: Why would it call anything else?

Comment: Okay, I understand your answer. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`def run()` in D overrides the `def run()` in C.  So when you call `run()` in `C.__enter__`, it actually calls `D.run()`.
When `D.run()` is called the `super().run()` calls `C.run()`.

It was just as confusing to me the first time I learned about python class inheritance but that's just how it works.